# Modify the text content of XML tag

Tags: java, xml

How can I insert a new tag for each word from the text content of a tag?

If i have a xml like:

```
<root>
  <el> Text content for tag 
 </el>
</root>
```

I want the output to be:

```
  <root>
   <el> <new>Text</new> <new>content</new> <new>for</new> <new>tag</new>
   </el>
  </root>
```

Any idea?

Comment: From your tags, I think that you could use Java libraries for parsing the XML and inserting nodes in it.  Check out this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3248573/259889

Comment: Try using `split()` + XML DOM for parsing + DOM methods such as `createTextNode()`, `appendChild()`, etc. Search for "How to parse XML in Java"

Comment: You asked this before as part of a larger question. I included an answer based on that question (which is similar to this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already asked part of this question before here: **[Add new node in XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201168/add-new-node-in-xml-file)**

Based on that, I will use an example similar on the one you used in *that* question, which is a bit more complex than this one because the elements didn't contain plain text, but could have mixed content (elements and text).

The XML I am using there is the one you posted before:

```
<nodes>
    <RegDef>This <i>text</i> have i node.</RegDef>
    <RegDef>This text doesn't have i atribute.</RegDef>
</nodes>
```

Refer to the **[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201168/add-new-node-in-xml-file)**. In that question I call a method which I called `wrapWordsInContents()` which returns a new element with its words wrapped inside `<w>` elements. That new element is used to replace the old one. This is that method:

```
public static Element wrapWordsInContents(Element node, Document document) {
    NodeList children = node.getChildNodes();
    int size = children.getLength();
    Element newElement = document.createElement(node.getTagName());
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (children.item(i).getNodeType() == Document.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            newElement.appendChild(wrapWordsInContents((Element)(children.item(i)), document));
        } else { // text node
            String text = children.item(i).getTextContent().trim();
            if(text.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            String[] words = text.split("\\s");
            for(String word : words) {
                Element w = document.createElement("w");
                Node textNode = document.createTextNode(word);
                w.appendChild(textNode);
                newElement.appendChild(w);
            }
        }
    }
    return newElement;
}
```

Note that it recursively processes any child elements, wrapping any words it finds inside them with the `<w>` tag. If you want to use `<new>`, just replace `"w"` for `"new"`.

If you run the code in the previous question with this method, you will get a new document which will generate a XML that when serialized will produce this output:

```
<nodes>
    <RegDef><w>This</w><i><w>text</w></i><w>have</w><w>i</w><w>node.</w></RegDef>
    <RegDef><w>This</w><w>text</w><w>doesn't</w><w>have</w><w>i</w><w>atribute.</w></RegDef>
</nodes>
```

For the code example you posted in this question, you would use:

```
NodeList elNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("el");
int size = elNodes.getLength();
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    Element el = (Element)elNodes.item(i);
    Element newEl = wrapWordsInContents(el, document);
    Element parent = (Element)el.getParentNode(); // this is `<root>`
    parent.replaceChild(newEl, el);
}
```